# Getting into Weight Painting mode with multiple meshes

Tags: mesh, weight-painting

I created a character using the [MakeHuman](http://www.makehumancommunity.org/content/plugins.html) application so I now have multiple meshes for this character.

So there are separate meshes for the person, hair, shoes, clothes, eyes, and teeth.

I'm in Blender and I've added all the bones and I do the automatic weight painting thing OK.

But now I need to weight paint specific bones and getting into the weight painting mode is the problem.  If I only select one mesh then I can get into the mode, but I want to select all the meshes when I get into the weight painting mode.

There is no point in the skin of person moving with the bones when the clothes and hair move in a different directions.

So I need to select multiple meshes.

I know that to get into weight painting I select the armature and then select one mesh, which is not good enough.

How do I do this with multiple meshes?

Comment: If your only problem is that you want the person, clothes and hair move into the same direction when animated, it is not necessary to weight paint them all at once. You can do it one after another. The other possibility is, why not join the meshes into one with Ctrl+J? Since it doesn't sound like you want to do e.g. a cloth simulation on the clothes if you want them connected to the bones.

Comment: Cool Ctrl-J worked.  I had tried to join the meshes together with BoolTool but that went wrong as well.  But just a simple Ctrl-J worked, thank you.

Comment: The good thing is, _BoolTool_ might join the meshes so that overlapping parts get fused together. But if you simply join them with Ctrl+J, each object stays a separate mesh inside the object, so that for example you can simply select the hair by hovering your mouse over it and pressing L. No need to try to not accidentally select parts of the other meshes.